# How to pass by reference to function that won't accept new arguments?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I need to modify a parameter named `test` inside `process_data` and switch cases outside that function depending on `test` value.

I couldn't pass it by reference using `upvar` because the `process_data` represent a static function for processing received udp packet, and it won't accept more than two parameters 'size and data'.
Also, as far as I found, there is no returned value for the `process_data` function.

Code:

```
set test "0"

Agent/UDP instproc process_data {size data} {
     //some stuff
     if (...)
        set test "1"
}

// switch cases depending on test value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extra argument to use `upvar` if you know the name of the variable you're going to alias. You should be able to do either of these (do *not* use both):

```
global test
upvar #0 test test
```

It's not really classic modular programming, but it will work.

A good place to put the command is at the beginning of the procedure body, like so:

```
Agent/UDP instproc process_data {size data} {
    global test
    # some stuff
}
```

Same thing if you use `upvar #0 test test` (those two commands are basically equivalent).

Documentation:
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Comment: I'm not an expert in tcl coding, so can you please edit your answer to be more specific where to put each, use my example if you like. Thanks

Comment: Inside `process_data`, I can change `test` as I like, but outside `process_data` it stays "0" as I've set it in the beginning.

Comment: @EmadAldeen: is the outer `test` declared in a namespace or in some other scope than the global one?

Comment: `test` is declared in global scope, I need something similar to 'returned value' from `process_data`.

Comment: @EmadAldeen: if you use `global test`, the `test` variable outside the procedure will have the same value as the `test` variable inside it. Something is not right here. Can you edit your question to show more of your code?

Comment: sorry it was another issue, your answer worked. thanks